# Find a cyclic factorization of the Petersen graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

The book *Chromatic Graph Theory* by Chartrand and Zhang defines a **cyclic factorization** of a graph $G$ to be an isomorphic factorization (a partition of $G$ into $k$ isomorphic copies of a graph $H$) such that (in an appropriate drawing of $G$) rotating one copy of $H$ through a fixed angle $1, 2, \dots, k-1$ times produces the other copies.

Exercise 9 in chapter 4 of this book asks:

> Give a cyclic factorization of the Petersen graph into
>
> (a) three factors,
>
> (b) five factors.

Could some give me a factorization, I don't really sure how can I find such factorization

Comment: I've edited your question such that someone who doesn't have a copy of your textbook lying around can hope to understand what you're asking. This is the sort of detail you should try to provide every time you ask a question - otherwise, the number of people who can answer your question is restricted substantially.

Answer (score 1):

Without any additional conditions on the cyclic factorization, you just need to divide the graph into copies of a subgraph $H$ that are rotations of each other.

For $5$ factors, you can just take the usual drawing of the Petersen graph. Here, if you rotate by $\frac{2\pi}{5}$, the edges are divided into three orbits, and you can pick one edge from each orbit. One way to do this (but not the only way) is shown below:

[image: cyclic factorization]

Then the other four factors are rotations of the highlighted edges.

For $3$ factors, you need to begin with a drawing of the Petersen graph that has order-$3$ rotational symmetry:

[image: petersen graph with order-3 symmetry]

Then it's the same as the first part: look at the orbits of the edges when you rotate by $\frac{2\pi}{3}$, pick an edge from each orbit, and you have one of the factors.

Comment: Can I ask how you draw to graph?

Comment: I use Mathematica; in this case, Mathematica's `Graph` command (with a specified list of coordinates for the vertices in the second drawing, and the default embedding of the Petersen graph in the first).